# Update List via Redux's Reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, reducers

I am making a small recipe list for learning purposes on React (since I am new to it).

I was able to figure out how to ADD and DELETE recipes from the list. However I am hard time how to EDIT a recipe  from the list (App's state).

Following from Redux's document:

> Because we want to update a specific item in the array without
>   resorting to mutations, we have to create a new array with the same
>   items except the item at the index.

I am having trouble how select the specific item in the array when the array that is selected itself is modified.

Here is my Actions file:

**src/actions**

```
export const RECIPE_ADD = 'RECIPE_ADD';
export const RECIPE_EDIT = 'RECIPE_EDIT';
export const RECIPE_DELETE = 'RECIPE_DELETE';
export function addRecipe(recipe) {
  return {
    type: RECIPE_ADD,
    payload: recipe
  }
}
export function editRecipe(recipe) {
  return {
    type: RECIPE_EDIT,
    payload: recipe
  }
}
export function deleteRecipe(recipe) {
  return {
    type: RECIPE_DELETE,
    payload: recipe
  }
}
```

**src/reducers/reducer_recipe**

```
import { RECIPE_ADD } from '../actions/index';
import { RECIPE_DELETE } from '../actions/index';
import { RECIPE_EDIT } from '../actions/index'

const defaultList = [
  { recipe: 'Pizza', ingredients: ['tomato-sauce','cheese','peperoni'] },
  { recipe: 'Pie', ingredients: ['dough','cherry'] },
  { recipe: 'Curry', ingredients: ['rice','sauce','carrots'] },
];

export default function(state = defaultList, action){
  switch (action.type) {
    case RECIPE_ADD:
      return [
        { recipe: action.payload[0], ingredients: action.payload[1] },
        ...state
      ];
    case RECIPE_DELETE:
    let index = state.map(x => x.recipe).indexOf(action.payload.recipe)
      return (
        state.slice(0,index).concat(state.slice(index + 1))
      )
    case RECIPE_EDIT:
    console.log(action.payload)
    // action.payload is the updated selected recipe
      return (
        state
      )
  }
  return state;
}
```

I suspect I need to add an id in the actions to differentiate it from the array list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should add an id to objects in defaultList:

```
const defaultList = [
  { id: 1, recipe: 'Pizza', ingredients: ['tomato-sauce','cheese','peperoni'] },
  { id: 2, recipe: 'Pie', ingredients: ['dough','cherry'] },
  { id: 3, recipe: 'Curry', ingredients: ['rice','sauce','carrots'] },
];
```

Then update your recipe:

```
    case RECIPE_EDIT:
      return state.map((recipe)=> {
        if( recipe.id == action.payload.id ) {
          return action.payload
        } else {
          return recipe;
        }
      });
```

You should use `===` instead of `==` on if condition only if you are sure that `recipe.id` and `action.payload.id` are both Integer.

Comment: Awesome, I took your idea and implemented in my action file:

`export function addRecipe(recipe) {
  const id = shortid.generate();
  return {
    type: RECIPE_ADD,
    payload: recipe,
    id: shortid.generate()
  }
}`

It did the trick to pick the selected recipe correctly

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like that to work:

```
import { RECIPE_ADD } from '../actions/index';
import { RECIPE_DELETE } from '../actions/index';
import { RECIPE_EDIT } from '../actions/index'

const defaultList = [
  { recipe: 'Pizza', ingredients: ['tomato-sauce','cheese','peperoni'] },
  { recipe: 'Pie', ingredients: ['dough','cherry'] },
  { recipe: 'Curry', ingredients: ['rice','sauce','carrots'] },
];

export default function(state = defaultList, action){
  switch (action.type) {
    case RECIPE_ADD:
      return [
        { recipe: action.payload[0], ingredients: action.payload[1] },
        ...state
      ];
    case RECIPE_DELETE:
      let index = state.map(x => x.recipe).indexOf(action.payload.recipe)
        return (
          state.slice(0,index).concat(state.slice(index + 1))
        )
    case RECIPE_EDIT:
      return state.map((recipe)=> {
        if( recipe.name === action.payload.name ) {
          return action.payload
        } else {
          return recipe;
        }
        return recipe;
      });
  }
  return state;
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that user can edit the recipe and/or the ingredients itself. So this wouldnt work